# Non-existent constant return true

Tags: php, constants

Each time user logs in, I extract a serialized array containing rights. When I unserialize the array and try to assign each right to a constant, non-existent constants return TRUE. For instance, here is my call to database :

```
    $req_level = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM users_levels WHERE level_id = ?');
    $req_level->execute(array($row['level_id']));
    $row_level = $req_level->fetch();
    $user_level_name = $row_level['name'];
    $permissions = unserialize($row_level['permissions']);
    foreach ($permissions as $permission) {
        define(strtoupper($permission), 1);
    }
    $req_level->closeCursor();
```

My array ($permissions) is :

```
Array ( [0] => users_read [1] => users_update [2] => customers_read [3] => customers_update )
```

When I call all possible constants I should get TRUE for those existing and FALSE for those non existing, but here is what I got...

```
USERS_READ : <?=USERS_READ?> <br/>
USERS_UPDATE : <?=USERS_UPDATE?> <br/>
USERS_CREATE : <?=USERS_CREATE?> <br/>
USERS_DELETE : <?=USERS_DELETE?> <br/>
```

When I echo constants...

- USERS_READ : 1
- USERS_UPDATE : 1
- USERS_CREATE : USERS_CREATE
- USERS_DELETE : USERS_DELETE

So everything returns TRUE in this case.

Any idea ?

Comment: This is what I've done here : define(strtoupper($permission), 1); No ?

Comment: `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically, in PHP, constants that are not found are turned into strings with the same name.  So, trying to use a constant 'USERS_READ' becomes the string 'USERS_READ' when attempted to be used.  The string 'USERS_READ' when converted to boolean will be true.

So, you need to use the method `defined` in order to check if it exists before trying to evaluate the constant:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.defined.php

Or, you could do something like this:

```
function userHasPermission( $permission ) {
    return constant($permission) === 1;
}
```

BTW - on a side note, using "dynamic constant" sounds like a design idea you might want to rethink. Constants are usually constant :)